# KeeperErrorCode = = NoNode for /brokers/topics/test-topic/partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, error-handling, apache-zookeeper

When running `zookeeper.bat` I get this error:

```
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x18941655fa30000
type:create cxid:0x1b9
zxid:0xda txntype:-1
reqpath:n/a
Error Path:/brokers/topics/private.tenantusers.download/partitions
Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/private.tenantusers.download/partitions (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

How could this be resolved so that I can run `zookeeper`.